# Auto comment with Facebook post with pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am writing python code to jump the mouse cursor to the comment box of a Facebook post as below to write a comment but not work, using google chrome.

```py
import pyautogui as P 
import time
import os

def StartChrome():
    command = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    os.startfile(command)  
    time.sleep(10)

def PostComment(fburl, fbcmt):
    P.hotkey('ctrl', 't')
    P.typewrite(fburl.lower())
    P.typewrite('\n')
    time.sleep(10)
    
    P.press("C")
    time.sleep(2)
    P.typewrite(fbcmt)
    P.press('enter') 

StartChrome()

PostComment('https://m.facebook.com/groups/1430431143824643/posts/1896340613900358/','Welcome')
```

Everything worked fine (opened new tab of chrome, loaded the post successful) but mouse cursor didn't move to the "Comment" box of the post after the line P.press("C"). Do I wrong anything of using hot key of facebook?

Comment: help us, help you. Please explain the issue about what you are facing, preferably with logs

Comment: I dont really use pytaugui, but you did not import os yet used the command `os.startfile(command)` but it also looks like you used  `P.hotkey('ctrl', 't')` which i guess you are using to make a new tab but you use a hotkey and not typing it. Please put the problem of the question too.

Comment: What do you mean "not work" ? Were there any error messages (if so, please post them)? What is your expect result? What is the current result - what happened, what keys were typed when you run the script?

Comment: No error messages but mouse cursor didn't move to the "Comment" box of the post after line P.press("C") was executed.

Comment: after run the Script, it opened new tab by using P.hotkey('ctrl', 't'), loaded URL by using P.typewrite(fburl.lower()) successful, but I want to move mouse cursor to the "Comment" box by using 'C' key (P.press("C")) but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Get a locationcenteronscreen with picture of the button loaded (make sure it's not scaled or edited, must be exact copy)into the argument, then call moveto function and then finally the click function, refer to document on the official site there is a tutorial on clicking buttons specifically.
Or reach out to me I'd be happy to help, I use pyautogui extensively